# Json Plugin and Global exception in Struts

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am trying to return a JSON formatted global exception. This is my current struts.xml. I am not sure what is it that I am missing.

```
<struts>

<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
<constant name="struts.configuration.xml.reload" value="true" />

<package name="mkaStrive" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor" />
        <interceptor-stack name="mobileStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="json" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="test" />

    <global-results>

        <!-- Exceptions are handled by ExceptionAction -->
        <result name="exception" type="chain">
            <param name="actionName">exception</param>
        </result>

    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Throwable" result="exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="exception" class="n.a.exception.ExceptionAction" />

    <action name="getQuestionsList" class="n.a.mkastrive.action.GetQuestions" method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="json" />
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action>       
</package>
```

My GetQuestions action for now simply throws exception:

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("TEST");
}
```

From here ideally it should see that I have global-results and then chain to the action named exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see in the `struts.xml` you provide is the below :(typo ?)

Use

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="mobileStack" />
```

Instead of

```
<default-interceptor-ref name="test" />
```

With this, you could verify that the control comes inside the `execute` method of `exception action` class : `n.a.exception.ExceptionAction`.

Now, if you were to return a response that customises the thrown exception, you can include a `json` result as so:

```
<action name="exception" class="n.a.exception.ExceptionAction" >
  <result type="json"></result>
</action>
```

And for getting the Exception instance that was thrown from `GetQuestions.execute()`, you can use below in the exception action's `execute` method:

`(Exception)ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().findValue("exception");`

You can operate on this and set required private fields in the class, so that they are available via public getters for json rendering. Just linking to a [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/)  for json response.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can try this again. But I moved onto Spring.